# installing ubuntu 12.10

Tags: system-installation

I waited for 3 h and interrupted the install from a dvd and there was no loader for ubuntu, even though Windows started after shrinking its partition. I restarted the installation and have let it go for 3 h, but other than the little wheel turning there doesn't seem to be anything going on...there is no option to restart, only suspend. Is this normal? All the system files appear to be there, although grub is not configured for dual boot...

Comment: Give us more details. It is a little ambiguous, If there is no boot loader then how do you access Ubuntu? Using other stuffs?

Comment: I booted from the dvd again. Right now I am waiting as it installs (4 h), although I am able to browse the web and look at everything on my comp, all disks and partitions. But the little wheel keeps on turning. How will I know its done?

Answer (score 0):

First disconnect you machine from internet, being connected to the internet will make installer download some packages from ineternet (if possible!) and that's why you have to wait a long time, then I think you will be able to finish installation properly, so boot loader will be installed correctly. Also try to make sure that your downloaded iso image file has been downloaded properly. You can do this by checking md5sum.